# How to retrieve data from API using nodejs coffeescript

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

> I have an API and i want to retrieve API data.I am using nodeJS and
>   coffeescript.How can i write nodejs script using coffeescript.Here is
>   my API and want to retrieve data from that API.Please help me.
>
> http://apiprod.yourstory.com/v1/site/YOURSTORY/articles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to install request package using npm and use below code :

```
var request = require('request');
//Lets try to make a HTTP GET request to modulus.io's website.
request('http://www.modulus.io', function (error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body); // Show the HTML for the Modulus homepage.
}
});
```

Below link explains in more detail :

http://blog.modulus.io/node.js-tutorial-how-to-use-request-module

Comment: I have done according to your reply,but i got error /home/mohit/api.yourstory/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:216
      throw helpers.updateSyntaxError(err, stripped, filename);
      ^

/home/mohit/api.yourstory/app/api/v1/broadcastPush.coffee:157:80: error: unmatched )
        return console.log('Invalid Status Code Returned:', response.statusCode)
                                                                               ^
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Hey can you pls accept this as answer if it has helped you?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green (see screenshot below). I think you have done it since I can see the check mark. Thanks!